# Alternative to long if-statement

Tags: php, if-statement

If I have an if-statement that has its conditions constructed like this:

`if((condition 1) && (condition 2) && (condition 3))`

And I want to add an else-if clause where the conditions are the same but one of them (let's say the last one) is now false instead of true, is there a way of expressing this without having to resort to doing this:

```
if((condition 1) && (condition 2) && (condition 3))
{
  //Some code
}
else if((condition 1) && (condition 2) && !(condition 3))
{
  //Some code
}
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to store the result of the condition(s) that I want to be true in both cases beforehand using a variable:

`$x = (condition 1) && (condition 2) ? true : false;`

But is there a better alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the conditions:

```
if ( (condition 1) && (condition 2) ) {
    if (condition 3) {
      //Some code
    } else {
      //Some other code
    }
}
```

Comment: My only issue with this is that for the sake of code complexity it isn't so super to have nested if statements.

Comment: I don't see the point in this statement. You have two alternatives: 1. complex conditions or 2. complex structure. You cannot magically hide away that complexity. All you might try is aproving readability by stashing the inner parts away in separate functions, thus keeping the calling scope short and clean. But then an object oriented approach might even make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with

```
if((condition 1) && (condition 2))
  {
  if (condition 3)
    {
    //Some code
    }
  else
    {
    //Some code
    }
  }
```

However, I have to question the logic here. Are condition 1 and 2 required to happen? Then you could simplify it greatly by doing:

```
if (!(condition 1))
  throw new Exception("Condition 1 didn't happen");

if (!(condition 2))
  throw new Exception("Condition 2 didn't happen");

if (condition 3)
  {
  //Some code
  }
else
  {
  //Some code
  }
```

You should choose the types of Exceptions depending on your condition, or maybe not even choose to throw an exception at all. But, in this way, your code gets greatly simplified. And that should be your main objective: to **fight complexity**. When you start getting into several nested conditionals you start to make your code unmaintainable.

Comment: Well the conditions are based on user input and they aren't always going to be true, it depends on what the user inputs. So yes they are required.